# How to Convert OAISYS .PVD File to .MP3 or .WAV File Format?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have tons of OAISYS PVD (Portable Voice Document) Call Recording Audio Files that are stored in my file system, I need to deploy these files on a web server and allow the website user to download these files in a playable format (like MP3 or WAV, or whatever playable) using some PVD Audio Converter, or at least, I need to let the user to listen to these recordings online (using some PVD Online Audio Player).

I spent hours searching for such an API or code that may help, but all what I found was some windows apps from OAISYS itself:

[1- OAISYS Stand Alone PVD Player (A.K.A Multicall PVD Player)](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2538321/assets/PDF/support/schedule-a-training/oaisys-training/oaisys_stand_alone_pvd_player.pdf?t=1495818879916), which can be used to play PVD files on windows, but it's a standalone windows app, which not what I need (I need a web service).

[2- OAISYS Management Studio](http://videos.mitel.com/watch/XlXjaBGMi3U8AsTaRNIJaQ), Available for System Admins, it allows the user to download any call recording as MP3, WAV, etc... (which is great, but not what I need). This program can be used for calls on OAISYS server, and my calls aren't in my case, they are saved on some server's file system. Maybe, not sure, but maybe the user can open (import) PVD files from file system and convert them using this program, but it is very hard to use this program with tons (millions) of PVD files, I need something more practical.

So, I need some code or API that can be used in my website to deal with these files (convert or play them online).

NOTE: Please keep in mind that these files aren't saved on OAISYS server, which means I CANNOT use OAISYS APIs to deal with them (like HistoricalCalls API or Playback API) that mentioned in [these Docs](https://manualzz.com/doc/29222624/api-overview-and-developer-s-guide)